# Paint app for ipad [opengl-es] line strokes not proper

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad, opengl-es

I have a strange problem with openGL. I am working on paint app for both iphone and ipad. I am using opengl-es for my app. In my app I am filling colors in outline images, drawings a line onscreen based on where the user touches. I just use the "touchesMoved" function to draw a line between two points. Since I would like lines to stay on screen, in my renderLineFromPoint function, but for some reason some of the points of the line just drop out, and it appears completely random. However **ipad simulator** and **iphone device/simulator** gives desired output. Line stroke appears as shown in figure.

[image]

I am creating buffer using following code:

```
- (BOOL)createFramebuffer{
// Generate IDs for a framebuffer object and a color renderbuffer
glGenFramebuffersOES(1, &viewFramebuffer);
glGenRenderbuffersOES(1, &viewRenderbuffer);

glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, viewFramebuffer);
glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, viewRenderbuffer);
// This call associates the storage for the current render buffer with the EAGLDrawable (our CAEAGLLayer)
// allowing us to draw into a buffer that will later be rendered to screen wherever the layer is (which corresponds with our view).

[context renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES fromDrawable:(id<EAGLDrawable>)self.layer];


glFramebufferRenderbufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, viewRenderbuffer);

glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH_OES, &backingWidth);
glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT_OES, &backingHeight);


NSLog(@"Backing Width:%i and Height: %i", backingWidth, backingHeight);


// For this sample, we also need a depth buffer, so we'll create and attach one via another renderbuffer.
glGenRenderbuffersOES(1, &depthRenderbuffer);
glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, depthRenderbuffer);
glRenderbufferStorageOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16_OES, backingWidth, backingHeight);
glFramebufferRenderbufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, depthRenderbuffer);

if(glCheckFramebufferStatusOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE_OES)
{
    NSLog(@"failed to make complete framebuffer object %x", glCheckFramebufferStatusOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES));
    return NO;
}

return YES;
```

}

I am using following code snippet for renderLineFromPoint

```
- (void) renderLineFromPoint:(CGPoint)start toPoint:(CGPoint)end{
static GLfloat*     vertexBuffer = NULL;
static NSUInteger   vertexMax = 64;

NSUInteger          vertexCount = 0,
                    count,
                    i;

[EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context];
glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, viewFramebuffer);

// Convert locations from Points to Pixels
//CGFloat scale = self.contentScaleFactor;
CGFloat scale;
if ([self respondsToSelector: @selector(contentScaleFactor)])
{

    scale=self.contentScaleFactor;

}
else{


//scale = 1.000000;

    if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)] == YES && [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] == 2.00) {
        // RETINA DISPLAY

        scale = 2.000000;
    }
    else {
        scale = 1.000000;
    }

}


NSLog(@"start point %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(start));

NSLog(@"End Point %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(end));



start.x *= scale;
start.y *= scale;
end.x *= scale;
end.y *= scale;

// Allocate vertex array buffer
if(vertexBuffer == NULL)
//  vertexBuffer = malloc(vertexMax * 2 * sizeof(GLfloat));


vertexBuffer = malloc(vertexMax * 2 * sizeof(GLfloat));


// Add points to the buffer so there are drawing points every X pixels
count = MAX(ceilf(sqrtf((end.x - start.x) * (end.x - start.x) + (end.y - start.y) * (end.y - start.y)) / kBrushPixelStep), 1);

NSLog(@"count %d",count);

for(i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    if(vertexCount == vertexMax) {
        vertexMax = 2 * vertexMax;
        vertexBuffer = realloc(vertexBuffer, vertexMax * 2 * sizeof(GLfloat));

        NSLog(@"if loop");

            }

    vertexBuffer[2 * vertexCount + 0] = start.x + (end.x - start.x) * ((GLfloat)i / (GLfloat)count);
    vertexBuffer[2 * vertexCount + 1] = start.y + (end.y - start.y) * ((GLfloat)i / (GLfloat)count);

    vertexCount += 1;
}


NSLog(@"Scale  vertex %f",scale);

//NSLog(@"%i",vertexCount);




// Render the vertex array
glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);

glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, vertexCount);


// Display the buffer
glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, viewRenderbuffer);
[context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES];
```

}

touchbegan function code:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
CGRect              bounds = [self bounds];
UITouch*    touch = [[event touchesForView:self] anyObject];
firstTouch = YES;
// Convert touch point from UIView referential to OpenGL one (upside-down flip)
location = [touch locationInView:self];
location.y = bounds.size.height - location.y;
```

}

touchmoved function code:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{  

CGRect              bounds = [self bounds];
UITouch*            touch = [[event touchesForView:self] anyObject];

// Convert touch point from UIView referential to OpenGL one (upside-down flip)
if (firstTouch) {
    firstTouch = NO;
    previousLocation = [touch previousLocationInView:self];
    previousLocation.y = bounds.size.height - previousLocation.y;

} else {
    location = [touch locationInView:self];
    location.y = bounds.size.height - location.y;
    previousLocation = [touch previousLocationInView:self];
    previousLocation.y = bounds.size.height - previousLocation.y;
}

// Render the stroke
[self renderLineFromPoint:previousLocation toPoint:location];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with missing points and it was related to the drawableProprties of my CAEAGLLayer.

Within CAEAGLLayer's drawableProperties, do you have the kEAGLDrawablePropertyRetainedBacking set to YES? If not then the Backing of your drawing is not being retained from frame to frame which can cause missing points and flickering.

Comment: Hey robhasacamera thank you for the reply but I have set kEAGLDrawablePropertyRetainedBacking to YES. This missing points problem occurs when I resize CAEaglelayer. If I set width n height of layer 768x768 its working properly but when I increase the height beyond 768  i.e. making it 768x769 it shows somthing wierd as shown in screenshot. Do you have any idea why is it happening ?

Comment: Does the issue happen when CAEAGLLayer starts out as 768x768 and you increase it to 768x768+n after drawing has occurred? Or does the issue also happen if you initialize it to 768x768+n?

Comment: problem occurs when i initialize my CAEagleLayer to 768x768+n.